# GPG Decryption Using Python (as a Windows Service)

Tags: python, windows, service, gnupg

I am using python-gnupg to decrypt files I am downloading that are encrypted. I have already built an executable that works perfectly but **the issue I am having is when I run it as a Windows Service.** For some odd reason when I install and run my executable as a Windows Service it fails to decrypt my files.

I think my issue may be with the scope of the service/where my files reside but I can't seem to find out why. I have added the path to gpg.exe to my PATH environment variable for the system and the gpg files are in my C: drive (not a local users).

I am using Kleopatra to store my certificates as well.

**So essentially there is some conflict between GPG and Windows Services and I cannot figure out why**. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Keyring is accessible only by you. Very likely even the system user under which services are runby default  cannot access it. Did you try to run the service as your user?

Comment: when I log on as my user, it still cannot decrypt

Comment: I do not mean you to log on on your windows box, but to configure the windows service to use the credentials of your user instead of the default system user.

Comment: How do I configure the service to run as my user? (Sorry, this is my first time working with windows service.)

Comment: Windows -> run `services.msc`. In services, find your service send select it. Select "Properties" from the context menu. A property page opens. In the second tab, you can enter your user name and your password. Then restart the service.

Comment: That is what I meant when I said I logged on as my user. But I figured it out, I had to set the home directory and binary to the gpg executable within my python script. Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, you might want to post it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

by giving a direct path to the gpg home directory and to the gpg binary location within my python script like this `gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="C:\path_to_gnupg" ,gpgbinary="C:\path_to_gpg.exe")` the service was able to run directly. It must have been having troubles locating the secret keys on its own.